# Can later be used for expressing distance?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I was wondering if " Can you stop at the later gate?" when trying to ask a cab driver to stop at gate 8 instead of 4 was a valid way of saying it?

Comment: It doesn't sound very natural. Why not just say the number of the gate you want?

Comment: It is later because the cab reaches it later (in time), not because of the number nor because of the distance, except indirectly.

Comment: But later come gate 5,6,7 as well. How do you differentiate that it is precisely gate 8 you mean?

Comment: ,,, And what if the cab is going the other way (past gates 12, 11, 10 ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically it is correct however I've never heard a native English speaker refer to an object as an earlier or later object. (You could say "The painting that we saw earlier.")